# PHP If statements not working when filtering SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Here's my problem: I have a set of inputs that are used to "filter" an SQL table. When Using one "filter" my code works fine, but when I try to use more than one (ie $states and $keywords) it will give me only one filter. In this case only the $states are used. BE AWARE, In the code below I'm using simple strings to test what the (Pseudo) SQL statement is will look like. I need one, or any combination of "filters" to work. I have a feeling my if statements are coming back true prematurely? or maybe just structured wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="ask-topics" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> 
<div>
    <input id="all" type="radio" name="opt" value="all" /><label for="all">ALL documents</label>
    <input id="new" type="radio" name="opt" value="new"/><label for="new">NEW documents</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="keywords" type="text" class="text-box" name="keywords" placeholder="Type keywords..." />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="conn" type="checkbox" name="state_chk[0]" class="state-chk" value="CT" /><label for="conn">Conn.</label>
    <input id="nh" type="checkbox" name="state_chk[1]" class="state-chk" value="NH"/><label for="nh">N.H.</label>
    <input id="nj" type="checkbox" name="state_chk[2]" class="state-chk" value="NJ" /><label for="nj">N.J.</label>
    <input id="ny" type="checkbox" name="state_chk[3]" class="state-chk" value="NY"/><label for="ny">N.Y.</label>
    <input id="vt" type="checkbox" name="state_chk[4]" class="state-chk" value="VT" /><label for="vt">VT</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="submit" class="button-link" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

PHP/SQL(Pseudo)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$keyword = $_POST['keywords'];
$states = $_POST['state_chk'];
$doc_opt = $_POST['opt'];
$query_filter = "";
$new_query = "Select `some colunms`
            FROM `this_table` 
            LEFT JOIN this_other_table 
            ON this_other_table.column = this_table.categoryid"; // Add WHERE/ORDER BY after
    if ($states){
        $query_filter = " A WHERE statement to get state specific documents";
    } 
    elseif($keyword){
        $query_filter = "a WHERE statemenrt to filter keywords";
    }
    elseif($doc_opt == "new"){
         $query_filter = " an ORDER BY statement to show only new documents";
    }
    // USING MULTIPLE FILTERS
    elseif($keyword && $doc_opt == "new"){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE and ORDER BY statement for getting keywords and new documents";
    }
    elseif($doc_opt == "new" && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE and ORDER BY statement for getting state specific docs and new docs";
    }
    elseif($keyword && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE statement for getting keywords and state specific docs";
    }
    else{
        $query_filter = " a generic WHERE AND ORDER BY statement";
    }
            echo $new_query.=$query_filter;
}
```

UPDATED PHP:

```
// CHECK FOR MULTIPLE FILTERS FIRST!
    if ($keyword && $doc_opt == "new" && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE/ORDER BY statemenrt to filter all three cases";
    } 
    elseif($keyword && $doc_opt == "new"){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE/ORDER BY statemenrt to filter keywords and new documents";
    }
    elseif($doc_opt == "new" && $states){
         $query_filter = " a WHERE/ORDER BY statemenrt to filter new documents by specific states";
    }
    elseif($keyword && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE statemenrt to filter keywords and specific states";
    }
    elseif($doc_opt == "new" && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE/ORDER BY statemenrt for getting state specific new documents";
    }
    elseif($keyword && $states){
        $query_filter = " a WHERE statement for getting keywords in state specific documents";
    }
    // IF NO MULTIPLE CASES CHECK FOR INDIVIDUAL CASES SECOND!
    elseif ($states){
        $query_filter = " A WHERE statement to get state specific documents";
    }
    elseif ($keyword){
        $query_filter = "a WHERE statement to filter keywords";
    }
    elseif ($doc_opt == "new"){
        $query_filter = " an ORDER BY statement to show only new documents";
    }
    // IF NO FILTER INPUTS WERE USED GET A GENERIC SET OF RESULTS LAST!
    else{
        $query_filter = " a generic WHERE AND ORDER BY statement";
    }
```

Comment: one filter -- `WHERE filter` two filters -- `WHERE filter1 AND filter2` -- your code does not follow this format.

Comment: When using elseif, if the conditions of the previous statement are met, then the elseif statement will never be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have elseif it's probably going through one of the first ones and not the multiple. So hence not combining the query together. Placing the multiple first and then the more normal/default last should sort the problem.

FYI I wouldn't be using this to make sql - you should use something like fluentPDO
http://envms.github.io/fluentpdo/

Things like this make your code more secure and a lot easier to make SQL queries.

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Thanks for that insight. I updated to reflect that idea. Also, I'll be looking into fluentPDO now that I know its a thing.